# Why is the ESRB rating of God of War "Mature 17+“?

Tags: video-games, god-of-war

The ESRB rating of *God of War* (PlayStation 2) is "Mature 17+“. When I first played it, I was 17 but ended up seeing Oracle’s boobs. [Here’s the video](https://youtu.be/JUvNN6lXHbk) (NSFW).

Why isn’t its rating "Adults Only 18+“ given open nudity is present?

Comment: Guys, don’t change the rating name. 17+ and 18+ are part of the official names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ESRB website gives this description of the [next game in the series](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/28666/God+of+War+III/), also an ESRB - 17 (Mature) rating

> This is an action-adventure game in which players assume the role of a half-human, half-god-like Spartan (Kratos) who seeks revenge against the gods of Mount Olympus. Steeped in ancient Greek mythology, the game depicts a fantasy world on an epic scale.
>
> It also depicts exaggerated acts of violence and frequent killing. Using double-chained blades and arrows, players hack-and-slash skeleton soldiers, rabid dogs, a centaur, a cyclops, fire-breathing creatures, and other monsters. This combat is both bloody and fantastical. Large sprays of red blood occur when enemies are hit. Blood often stains the ground, surrounding walls, and sometimes on Kratos' body. When defeated, enemies drop magical, glowing orbs that boost health and experience. The most intense depictions of violence occur during boss battles with the gods. Players engage in close-up and extended battles that are completed by pressing button sequences corresponding to on-screen prompts. One god will be thrown repeatedly into rocks and walls; another god's eyes will be gauged out by thumbs. A god may get pummeled into the ground or have its legs sliced off, its head torn off. In one sequence, blood will stain the screen after each of Kratos' blows, building up to the point of complete saturation. Immediately after "dying," the defeated gods often have fantastical endings such as transforming into a swarm of mitelike insects or a cascade of plummeting water.
>
> The game contains a sex mini-game. Players will encounter a goddess and her two hand maidens, all topless, all holding and caressing each other. If players wish to, they may join the goddess (and only the goddess) in bed. Actual sex is never depicted as the camera drifts, then fixes on the two maidens, who watch from a distance. As players respond to the on-screen prompts with button presses, the topless maidens will continue to watch, and sometimes caress. Moaning sounds from the bed can be heard throughout the sequence.
>
> The game includes some behind-the-scenes footage that contains a few instances of profanity (e.g., "f**k" and "sh*t").

Note the absence of any indicators of

> "Intense Violence" or "Prolonged sexual content"

As these would push it into the [rarely-used](https://screenrant.com/video-games-originally-rated-ao/) ESRB 18+ (Adults Only) AO category, likely resulting in a [significant loss of sales](https://www.polygon.com/2014/2/10/5362502/adults-only-rating-pointless-and-harmful-games-as-art-form) since various stores and [platforms](https://www.vg247.com/twitch-ao-games-banned-streaming) have a policy of not carrying these games, and difficulty in selling the game overseas in less permissive markets, it's likely that the makers would do everything possible to test the limits of the 17 rating, without breaking it.

Comment: The "AO" category carries significant import/export penalties on a lot of countries, and are generally just considered "trashy porn" and not particularly good for a video game. There is really no good reason to not avoid the AO rating, and the notoriety of the rating is completely offset by the import/export laws attached to it.

Comment: @Nelson - An excellent point. Since only a tiny number of games have ever received the AO rating, it's presumably quite easy to avoid

Answer (score 9):

According to the [ESRB website](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/), the 18+ rating is for "graphic sexual content". Less graphic sexual content is fine at the 17+ rating. A game marked M for Mature "may contain intense violence, blood and gore, sexual content and strong language." Similarly, for [the European PEGI ratings](https://pegi.info/what-do-the-labels-mean) 16+ can feature "erotic nudity or sexual intercourse without visible genitals" whilst 18+ would be for "explicit sexual activity". Nudity alone in a non-sexual context doesn't attract a specific PEGI rating at all, so is potentially fine in games for any age group.